# Does pyzmq flush a message without a sleep()?

Tags: queue, zeromq

I am using `zeromq` `PUB/SUB` pattern, a simple example is as follow:

```
def test_pubber(self):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.bind(ZMQ_PUB_ADDR)

    for i in range(2):
        socket.send("10001 end")
        time.sleep(1)
```

so this is ok, but if I do not sleep a while, it doesn't flush the message:

```
    for i in range(2):
        socket.send("10001 end")
```

how to flush the message?

Comment: roger, **by what means do you prove**, a particular scenario **did** / **did not** flush a message?

Comment: @user3666197 I think I have find where problem is, `bind` takes some time, so I need to do `time.sleep(1)` after bind. But any other way to solve this?